# Spring JPA one-to-one mapping can allow to save more items

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have relation one-to-one

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinColumn( name = "address_id" )
private Address address;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
private Customer customer;
```

I can add more than one address.
For example

```
Customer c1 = new Customer();
Address address = new Address();
addressRepo.save(address);
Customre c2 = new Customer();
c1.setAddress(address);
customerRopesitory.save(c1);
c2.setAddress(address);
customerRopesitory.save(c2);
```

i want to see throw when address2 is added but jpa allow it.
I want to block this at spring jpa level
How can i do it?

Comment: Can you share the Customer and Address classes?

Comment: actually it is not directly my code. i had a problem and i wrote same condition. so that i dont have classes

Answer (score 1):

I guess you question is "how to block using the same address twice" and throw an exception instead. I think you have to check this programmatically, something like `Assert.isTrue(customerRepository.countByAddress(address) == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the join column as unique:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", unique = true)
private Address address;
```

Hibernate will throw `DataIntegrityViolationException` when you try to save `c2` entity assigned with the same `address` entity.

Comment: This solution did not affect for my problem

Comment: @YusufYalcin ...then you should add some more details about your exact case with expected output so that you can get better help.

Comment: i changed my condiiton and i did one-to-one condition without relation. just save address id like Long value in customer class and i did unique this column. thank you for your help